# Recommendations for a development board for embedded programming

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded, arm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best Evaluation Kit for Learning Embedded C/C++ Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644889/what-is-the-best-evaluation-kit-for-learning-embedded-c-c-development)

I'm an electronics and software student and I'd like to enter the embedded devices world. At this point it's just a personal interest, not a career choice.

I'm somewhat experienced in C/C++ (mostly C++). I am an experienced linux user. I have an arduino but I dislike it because of the java layer on top. There are ways to upload C code on the device and I have done this.

However, at this point I'm a bit confused. I've seen dev. kits with debugger and programmer devices. I don't know what these are used for => I need info on those. There are also a lot of dev. kits out there that seem to offer various functions. Some come with software (MPLab on PICs) such as compilers and IDEs that make life easier.

I've searched for books and information but most either focus on some processor that I can't find (or costs $500). Others spend most time teaching C (I know C already).

Also I have the feeling that starting on an ARM processor would be best. I'm not sure that's the best processor to start with but they seem to have a lot of features and are very popular now. They also pack a significant throughput (I'm aware they also consume more power). Any recommendations on that?

I've looked at this: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/semiconductors/development-kits/microcontroller-processor/

A book recommendation would also be welcome. As I've said I've looked at some which focus on PIC (mostly) http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=embedded+systems&x=0&y=0

I've found a good book on ARM but I'm not sure it's for people new to embedded development. I think it might be for people new to ARM but with experience in embedded.

Thanks and hope it's not a double

Comment: What kind of Arduino has a *Java layer*?

Comment: Sorry I meant the compiler they provide translates java into C and then compiles it. I'd like to be able to write asm or C.

Comment: One possibility is any cheap router with a Broadcom chipset and a USB port. You can get Linksys E3000's, for example, refurbished for around $60. They have lots of RAM, flash, WiFi, Ethernet, and USB. They can run Linux.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no Arduino tools translate Java into C. The IDE itself is *written* in Java, but that doesn't mean that you're writing Java code when you use it. The Arduino IDE offers a C++ environment with some trivial wrapper code.

Comment: The longer you can avoid using a debugger, the happier you'll be.

Comment: A linksys e3000 router costs almost as much as a dev. board. And it will probably have limited documentation for the purposes of programming it.

Comment: @s5s: True, but it has greater capabilities than comparably priced dev boards. You don't need much documentation since it's running Linux -- you just need to talk to the OS. (That may be a plus or a minus depending on what you're trying to do.)

Comment: Don't vote to close this, the linked-to post is 3 years old. Thousands of newer and better MCUs have been released since then, so likely the same applies to dev kits.

Comment: @Lundin: That question does not ask what the best MCUs and kits **were in 2009**; it asks what the best ones **are**. Then again, shopping questions like these don't fly here anymore, either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know C or C++ and want to get a taste of embedded development, I'd also steer clear of Arduino as it has terrible price/performance compared to newer micros, particularly ARM Cortex devices. It has a great ecosystem and accessible toolchain, but if you aren't afraid to get down and dirty and work with some unfriendly tools, an ARM device will give you a better taste of embedded development.

At the moment I think the best deal out there is [STM32F4Discovery](http://www.st.com/internet/evalboard/product/252419.jsp) from STMicroelectronics. They are around $20, have a C SDK and toolchain, and it's a real, powerful part that you would use to design and embedded device. Lots of peripherals and CPU (for what it is); the Cortex M4 core is pretty much state of the art for microcontrollers. The only real downside with that board is it doesn't have a little LCD display, but the dev kits that do tend to be over $50 (although if you want something like that, the [TI/Stellaris Cortex M3 kits](https://estore.ti.com/Product3.aspx?ProductId=1894) are pretty nice too. You should be able to find plenty of resources for getting arm-eabi-gcc and OpenOCD (for program loading/debugging) set up on linux.

Raspberry Pi sounds like it has a chance to own this segment soon, although I think it may be a bit more software-driven environment as it is a full-blown linux system, although it has headers for peripherals it may actually be a bit harder to prototype a simple embedded system with RPi compared to an MCU kit depending on what you want to do. Same deal with BeagleBoard or PandaBoard, they are different classes of system and if you just want to learn some electronics and prototype an idea or two may actually be more complexity than you want. Unfortunately availability of Raspberry Pi is currently somewhere between incredibly limited and someday soon so it's actually not a viable choice if you want to order something today.

Comment: Thanks your answer is very useful. To be honest I've been looking at some ARM based boards but they seem to come with an embedded system installed. It seems to me that programming those would be more like writing software on a PC as the boards resemble a PC in functionality.

Comment: A Cortex M3 or M4 board should not come with an operating system as such. The ST and TI parts have C user libraries for the peripherals, but as far as system software goes you provide interrupt service routines and a main function, so it's pretty raw. I have run FreeRTOS on a TI/Stellaris board so there are options if you want to go that route, but it starts off pretty basic.

Answer (score 1):

[Neuros OSD](http://www.neurostechnology.com/osd) is pretty decent. You can get the Neuros OSD device for whatever they sell it for, and the whole software stack is open source code that you can work with freely. They have a decent Wiki-style documentation, and GNU based tool-chain. If I'm not mistaken its ARM-based.

I was able to bring it up and start writing code within hours. You might need a RS232 converter cable - send them an email and they'll ship you one if you can't find anything on eBay.

Answer (score 1):

[Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) is the new kid on the block. Developed specifically for learning, it runs Linux and is a fully capable computer on its own - no cross compiling necessary. Might be hard to get your hands on in the near term.

Comment: Yeah I just learned about it before asking this question. pandaboard seems OK too but it's $182. I can get the Pi for $35 and it's fast enough.

Comment: It also has GPIO, which is nice to have in a small microcomputer-class system.

Answer (score 0):

No problems using straight C and asm on the AVR, no reason to even install the java based sandbox, much less use it.  well depending on what you want to experience, if you want to write apps on an environment, it is perfect, if you want to learn embedded, then write embedded.  The price for what you get is a problem though.

The stm32f4 discovery about $20, surprising what they pack into a cortex-m4.  the stm32 value line discovery is almost half that and not bad, but I would go with the stm32f4.

The mbed family is okay, the cortex-m0 is easier to brick (well you can recover with a wee bitty wire and some solder).  Super easy to use though, you dont need their sandbox either if you dont want.

You might just play with the amber_samples repo/simulator.  You can get ARM asm and C embedded experience without spending a dime.   the amber processor is a clone of the arm2, the predecessor to the ARM's from ARM.  Only a few differences between this and the modern arms, and the differences are avoidable.  The thumbulator simulator, simulates the thumb instruction set which you find in the cortex-m microcontrollers.

There are a number of other simulators, skyeye, gdb, have arm simulators from what I understand.

Its not an arm, but for $5 you can get an msp430 launchpad board with a couple of different micros.  Easy to use, C/ASM, not a bad instruction set at all.

Answer (score 0):

And just to answer your question about debuggers - you need some way to load your program and debug it - and as microcontrollers typically do not come with keyboard and monitor, you have to do this from a host system. As you are writing code on the lowest level, you can't rely on Ethernet or even RS232, as these need to be set up in software on the microcontroller before they can be used.

This is where the debugger comes in. Newer ones connect to your computer using USB, and directly to your microcontroller through a JTAG interface (or one of its newer alternatives). The debugger allows you to load code directly into the embedded flash memory of the microcontroller, and to control its execution so you can debug it (single-stepping, breakpoints, memory inspection, etc) from your host.

A debugger is usually the only way to communicate with a completely empty microcontroller. You can then for instance program a bootloader, and let that start up alternative interfaces from where it can receive applications to run.

All in all, a debugger is an essential tool for embedded development. You wont get far without one. Many complete development kits come with their own debugger, but they can also be bought separately. I'm currently using an [Olimex ARM-USB-OCD-H](http://www.olimex.com/dev/arm-usb-ocd-h.html), for programming a custom board with an STM ARM-Cortex-M3 chip, though Eclipse on Windows7. The Olimex is probably not the best debugger out there, but it's cheap and has good support through open source software (such as OpenOCD as mentioned in one of the other answers - OpenOCD is the software used to communicate with the debugger, and is used to interface it to Eclipse's debugging tool).

And just to add another bit of advice - when starting out, it's a very good idea to get a development kit with everything include: board, debugger/programming cable and IDE. This will give you everything you need to get started, and is **a lot** easier than having to set up compilers/makefiles/debugging environments/startup code and such yourself (although one might argue that by doing this by hand you learn valuable information on how everything fits together, but it's usually not what a beginner wants to (or should have to) do at first).